GitHub file search by name results differ from web when using API or pyGitHub
I have a large git repo with multiple .Net solutions in it (in the example repo there is only one). I want to return the paths of all the Directory.Packages.props files within that specific repo. I am trying to use the code below:
from github import Github

token = '<my token>'

# Create a GitHub instance using the token
g = Github(token)

# Search for the file
result = g.search_code('Xcaciv/Xcaciv.Command', qualifiers={'path': '**/Directory.Packages.props'}) 

# Print the file content
print(result.totalCount)

I have tried several combinations for the parameters to search_code() without success. I feel like I am missing something simple but cannot see it. I have tried putting repo:Xcaciv/Xcacive.Command for the first parameter. I have tried to just use the string repo:Xcaciv/Xcaciv.Command path:**/Directory.Packages.props with no success. I have also tried calling the API directly in this same manner without success.
Each time I try I get HTTP 200 with a result of 0 (no results).
I appreciate any guidance.

you can use this
for all your repo:
from github import Github, RateLimitExceededException
import time


token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

g = Github(token)

def search_files(query):
    try:
        result = g.search_code(query)
        return result
    except RateLimitExceededException:
        print("Rate limit exceeded, waiting for reset...")
        core_rate_limit = g.get_rate_limit().core
        reset_timestamp = core_rate_limit.reset.timestamp()
        current_timestamp = time.time()
        wait_time = reset_timestamp - current_timestamp
        time.sleep(wait_time + 1)  
        return search_files(query) 


query = 'filename:Directory.Packages.props'
result = search_files(query)


print(f'Total files found: {result.totalCount}')
for file in result:
    print(f"File path: {file.path}")
    print(f"Repository: {file.repository.full_name}")
    print(f"URL: {file.html_url}")
    print("-" * 40)


as github has api has ratelimit ,we catch the rate limit error and wait until the limit resets before continuing
for single repository:
from github import Github, RateLimitExceededException
import time

token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'


g = Github(token, timeout=10)  

def search_files(query):
    try:
        print(f"Searching with query: {query}")
        result = g.search_code(query)
        print("Search completed.")
        return result
    except RateLimitExceededException:
        print("Rate limit exceeded, waiting for reset...")
        core_rate_limit = g.get_rate_limit().core
        reset_timestamp = core_rate_limit.reset.timestamp()
        current_timestamp = time.time()
        wait_time = reset_timestamp - current_timestamp
        print(f"Waiting for {wait_time + 1} seconds for rate limit reset...")
        time.sleep(wait_time + 1)
        return search_files(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

# Specify the repository name (owner/repo)
repo_name = 'owner/repo'

query = f'filename:Directory.Packages.props repo:{repo_name}'

result = search_files(query)

if result:
    print(f'Total files found: {result.totalCount}')
    for file in result:
        print(f"File path: {file.path}")
        print(f"Repository: {file.repository.full_name}")
        print(f"URL: {file.html_url}")
        print("-" * 40)
else:
    print("No results found or an error occurred.")


rate_limit = g.get_rate_limit()
print(f"Core rate limit remaining: {rate_limit.core.remaining}")


Note:
When using the GitHub search API, the 'filename:' qualifier is used to find files with a specific name, regardless of their directory or path. The API does not support a 'path:' qualifier for searching within specific directories.Instead, if you want to search for files within a specific directory, include the directory path in your query. For example, searching for files under a 'config' directory would look like 'config/Directory.Packages.props'. In this case, we use 'filename:' to ensure the search works as expected.

Thank you for your input to handle rate limits. However, I am getting HTTP200 responses (I clarified the question above). Also, your code is searching all of GitHub when I am concerned with a single repository.

ok let me modify the code for singel repository give me a moment

Ultimately the answer is to just use the text query directly. Your code does work when I place repo:Xcaciv/Xcaciv.Command filename:Directory.Packages.props as the query. This also worked in my example.

its my pleaseure but i was making a singel repo search for you :)

You should add a note in your answer about using filename: instead of path: or even file: like the pyGithub docs show. I never did get 'path' to work so as to use wildcard search from the api.

you can edit it @AC4 :)
